# MVC with no Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

From the below source tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt9vSY802mM
- http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/07/curd-operation-on-fullcalendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

How do I do the above code samples without Entity Framework, by just using SQL queries?

For example in the above source code, instead of

```
var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();  

if (v != null)
{
    dc.Events.Remove(v);
    dc.SaveChanges();
    status = true;
}
```

I want to do

```
DELETE FROM Even WHERE EventID = {0}
```

Comment: use ADO.NET classes e.g. SqlConnection etc. if it's MySQL then you'll need the MySQL specific libraries (e.g. MySQLConnection etc), you can download them from MySQL. If you don't know how to use them, find a tutorial, there are lots available online for free, you can google them and find some in a few seconds. Even if they cover the SQL Server libraries mainly, the basic idea is the same for MySQL, and the MySQL docs themselves have specific examples. Did you research your requirement at all??

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault()` in LINQ is equivalent to `LIMIT 1` in MySQL, hence the LINQ function can be converted to SQL commands using `IF` or `CASE WHEN` like this (assumed commands are running inside a stored procedure):

```
DELIMITER //

-- 'Events' is a DbSet name by common convention,
-- therefore table name should be 'Event'
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (IN eventID INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT;
    SET v = SELECT EventID FROM Event WHERE EventID = eventID LIMIT 1;

    CASE WHEN v IS NOT NULL 
    THEN DELETE FROM Event WHERE EventID = v
    ELSE -- do something else
    END

    -- alternative:
    -- IF(v IS NOT NULL, DELETE FROM Event WHERE eventID = v, 0)

    -- other stuff here

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** If `EventID` is a primary key column, you can remove `LIMIT 1` because query result only return single value.

Then, use `CALL procedure_name(eventID)` or include `procedure_name` in `MySqlCommand` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways:

1. using raw query in Entity Framework:
2. Open connection string via SqlConnection and execute:

Pseudo code for method 1:

```
string sqlDeleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Even WHERE EventID = @id";
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", 1)); delete id = 1
_context.Database.SqlQuery(sqlDeleteStatement, parameterList);
```

Pseudo code for method 2:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
{
   conn.ConnectionString = "Server=[server_name];Database=[database_name];Trusted_Connection=true";
   string sqlDeleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Even WHERE EventID = @id";
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlDeleteStatement , conn);
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", 1)); //delete id = 1
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```