# Convert EntityFramework to Raw SQL Queries in MVC

Tags: sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am trying to make a crud calendar in my .net, my question is, How do make the below entity framework codes to SQL queries?

```
[HttpPost]

public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)

{

var status = false;
using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    if (e.EventID > 0)
    {
        //Update the event
        var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            v.Subject = e.Subject;
            v.Start = e.Start;
            v.End = e.End;
            v.Description = e.Description;
            v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
            v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dc.Events.Add(e);
    }
    dc.SaveChanges();
    status = true;
}

return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };

}
```

http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/07/curd-operation-on-fullcalendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Thanks guys

Comment: Why you need to convert it to raw SQL, what is your intention?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRUD Calendar in MVC with no Entity Framework, just SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316121/crud-calendar-in-mvc-with-no-entity-framework-just-sql-queries) . Don't post what is (essentially) the same question twice, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run raw query in entity framework with `dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` command like below:

```
var status = false;
using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    if (e.EventID > 0)
    {
        dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(&@"
        UPDATE Events 
        SET Subject = {e.Subject},
        Start = {e.Start},
        End = {End},
        Description = {Description},
        IsFullDay = {IsFullDay},
        ThemeColor = {ThemeColor},
        WHERE EventID = {e.EventID}

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO Events (EventID, Subject, Start, End, Description, IsFullDay, ThemeColor)
        VALUES ({e.EventID}, {e.Subject}, ...)
        ");

        status = true;
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } 
};
```

Comment: Hi Hasan, thanks for the reply. I am using DBUTL.CS, is there a way to code it "pure" sql queries without any EntityFramework involve?

Comment: Hi, your-welcome, I don't know what is DBUTL.CS, but ADO.Net is the old way to connect to database and run raw query in c#.